# Suggest a similar installer for apache spark and a notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, installation, bigdata

I am new to bigdata analytics. I am trying to install apache spark and a notebook to execute code like iPython. Is there an installer that comes with both spark set up and a good notebook tool inbuilt. I come from a back ground in PHP and Apache. I am used to tools like xampp, wamp that install multiple services in once click. Can any one suggest a similar installer for apache spark and a notebook? I have windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If iPython is not a mandatory requirement and if you can work with Zeppelin notebook with Apache spark I think you will need Sparklet. Its similar to what you seek a xampp like installer for spark engine and zeppelin tool. 
You can see details here - [Sparklet](http://www.mund-consulting.com/Products/Sparklet.aspx) 
It supports windows. Let me know if it solves your problem.